# How to render table from from csv file into django templates?

Tags: python, django, csv

I have a problem with rendering table in django templates with data form csv file.
I'm reading data from file:

```
with open('data/file.csv', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
```

and rendering the template:

```
return render(request, 'search/search.html', {'data': reader})
```

and in the template:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>...</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    {% for row in data %}
       <td>{{row}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

and I have error

> operation on closed file

Firstly I thought about using pandas but in Django it gave me circular import :/
Could anyone let me know how can I fix it?

Comment: You store the reader values in list or dictionary based on your requirement then send it via render to template